# При использовании connect redux в компоненте, он не перерендеривается при обновлении родительского состояния

Tags: reactjs, redux

Код моего компонента следующий

```js
...
class UserItem extends Component {
    ...

    render() {
        const {language, classes, user} = this.props;
        return <div>

            ...

            <div className={classes.grower}> </div>
            {user.active === '1' && <Button onClick={this.onDeactivateClick} color='primary' mini>{language.universal.deactivate}</Button>}
        </div>
    }
}

const styles = theme => ({
    ...
});

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    return {
        language: state.language
    }
}

UserItem.propTypes = {
    classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    deactivateClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    user: PropTypes.object,
    onItemClick: PropTypes.func,
};

export default compose(
    withRouter,
    withStyles(styles, {withTheme: true}),
    connect(mapStateToProps, null)
)(UserItem);
```

[image: Пример отображения компонента]

В родительском компоненте в стейте есть массив users, в который загружаются с сервера примерно такие данные (я сократил, чтоб не засорять)

```json
[{
  "user_id": "70",
  "email": "test@manager56.com",
  "firstname": "Mila",
  "lastname": "Ferris",
  "date_added": "2019-05-27 20:13:43",
  "users_group_id": "3",
  "user_roles_id": "4",
  "avatar_id": "94",
  "thumbnail_img": "imgs\/avatars\/000094_tmb_img.jpg",
  "active": "1",
  "urole_id": "4",
  "urole_name": "manager",
  "urole_description": "Manager for stuffing type modules"
},...]
```

В родителе в рендере через map выводится список через мой компонент (код которого я привёл вначале). При изменениях в состоянии родителя могут меняться данные списка, например меняется состояние active у любого из пользователей. От этого ключа зависит отображается ли кнопка в компоненте или нет, а также подсветка. Но увы компоненты не перерендериваются.

Я весь день перебирал код, практически построчно. И в итоге выяснил, что если убрать из моего компонента connect(mapStateToProps, null), то всё работает как надо, и при изменении active в массиве тут же изменения отображаются в компоненте.

Конкретно в данной ситуации мне не критично важен этот connect, я выкрутился и передаю из родителя language через пропсы, но в будущем мне может понадобиться именно через редакс подгружать нужный мне пропс, поэтому хотелось бы понять почему так происходит и как этого избежать.

UPD:

Сокращённый код родительского компонента:

```js
...
class UsersList extends Component {
  state = {
    ...
    users: []
  };

  componentWillMount() {
    this.loadUsers()
  }


  loadUsers = page => {
    ...
  };

  startDeactivation = deactivate_user_id => this.setState({
    deactivate_user_id
  });

  deactivateUser = () => {
    ...
    if (success) {
      let users = this.state.users;
      users.forEach(
        user => {
          if (user.user_id === user_id) {
            user.active = '0'
          }
        }
      );
      this.setState({
          users
        })
        ...
    };

    render() {
      ...

      return <div className = {className}>
      {
          this.state.users !== undefined && this.state.users.length > 0 ? this.state.users.map(
            (user, index) => {
              return <UserItem deactivateClick = {this.startDeactivation}
              key = {index}
              user = {user}/>
            }) :
            <Card className = {classes.errorCard}> No users was found </Card>
        } 
        <div>
    }
  }

  const styles = theme => ({
   ...
  });

  function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    return {
      language: state.language
    }
  }

  UsersList.propTypes = {
    classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  };

  export default compose(
    withRouter,
    withStyles(styles, {
      withTheme: true
    }),
    connect(mapStateToProps, null)
  )(UsersList);
```

Изначально загружается список пользователей с сервера, затем пользователь выбирает определённого пользователя и срабатывает метод deactivateUser, в котором у определённого пользователя ключ active меняется на '0'. После этого внешний вид деактивированного итема в списке пользователей должен измениться. Но этого не происходит, если в компоненте этого итема имеется вышеописанный connect.

Comment: А почему компонент должен обновляться, если ни одно из его свойств не изменилось? Добавите родительский компонент (не полностью, а упрощенно - скажем, пусть там будет всего одна кнопка "изменить состояние").

Comment: @PavelMayorov алгоритм такой: родительский компонент имеет стейт users: [], этот массив наполняется объектами в котором один из ключей это active. Далее в рендере есть this.state.users.map, где достаем каждого пользователя из этого массива. В return метода map выдаётся как раз описанный в топике компонент <UserItem key={i} user={user}/> т.е. по логике если в одном из объектов этого массива произошло изменение, то логично что один из итемов должен перерендериться. И если в UserItem убрать connect, то так оно и происходит, а с ним вообще не работает.

Comment: Вы в вопрос описание добавьте, а не комментарием.

Comment: @PavelMayorov добавил